# I keep getting "ModuleNotFound" error when i try to run code on my terminal even though i installed it

Tags: python, error-handling, terminal, module, git-bash

i work with:

1. Atom as a text editor
2. GitBash as a terminal

i've been trying to work with the numpy module but, even though i installed it via conda command on my terminal, it still gives me the ModuleNotFoundError when i run my code on the terminal

For example, here's some code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL4JP.png

and here is me trying to run it on my terminal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChOWm.png

Comment: How/where did you install numpy? It might be an environment issue or multiple Python distributions!

Comment: run `pip list` or `python -m pip list` where you are executing your code and see if `numpy` is lsited there as installed modules. And, as you have installed it using conda, there might be some environment issues here.

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations? You may have installed it in one and trying to use it in another. For example, you can use ```ls -ls /usr/bin/python*``` to see what all python installations are there in your system. For other OS, check specific commands.

Comment: @jak123 >> I used the command "conda install numpy".on my gitbash terminal, and I downloaded python from python.org and the one that comes with anaconda by default.

Comment: @avats I have a problem with pip command even though I manually added it to my environmental variables it still gives me "pip not found error", that's why I downloaded conda in the first place.

Comment: python.org and anaconda are two different distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you have installed `numpy` using conda, run your script or `.py` file in anaconda prompt (`python yourfile.py`) instead of GitBash or windows command prompt.

Otherwise, add python to the path and make sure that you are adding the right variable to path. If you are using conda installation of python, then add that to your path or if you installed python standalone, you should add that to path. Use following commands to know where is python installed in your system and add to path accordingly. Then use GitBash or CMD to run your files.

In CMD:

```
where.exe python
```

In GitBash:

```
which python
```

or

```
where.exe python
```